# Save current state in ds9?

Tags: observational-astronomy, software, ds9

After fooling around with a FITS file(s) (e.g. setting scale, changing color) is it possible to save the session such that there is a file associated with all those tweaks the next time I open it up?

Save and Save Image just seem to keep whatever I set it to, but when I load those new saved files back into ds9 the settings are all back to whatever default load settings I have enabled.

I would also like to be able to do this if I have FITS files loaded into multiple frames so I don't have to go through the process of loading each individual image.

Comment: Did you try to `export`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for the backup function

> File -> Backup...

and to restore the settings

> File->Restore...

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for.